# Do aux routes work for the root component only?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having trouble setting up auxiliary routes in child components, for some reason only those auxiliary routes work that start at the root component.

Here's my router setup

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'test1', component: Test1Component },
    { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, outlet: 'aux'},        
    { path: 'shell', component: ShellComponent, children: [
        { path: 'department/:id', component: DepartmentDetailComponent },
        { path: 'test3', component: Test3Component, outlet: 'aux2' }         ] }
];
```

If I navigate to

```
http://localhost:3000/shell/department/1(aux:test2)
```

then the output is as expected, that is, `Test2Component` is rendered inside `AppComponent`, along with `ShellComponent` and `DepartmentDetailComponent`:

[image: Blue: Primary Outlet, Red: Aux Outlet]

Primary outlets show up in blue, auxiliary outlets in red.

If, however, I try to navigate to

```
http://localhost:3000/shell/department/1(aux2:test3)
```

I get an error message:

> platform-browser.umd.js:1900 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'test3'

`router-outlets` are as follows:

**app.component.ts (aux: test2)**

```
<div class="app">
  <h1>App</h1>
  <div class="primary-outlet">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="aux-outlet">
    <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**shell.component.ts (aux2: test3)**

```
<div class="component">
  <h1>Shell</h1>
  <div class="primary-outlet">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="aux-outlet">
    <router-outlet name="aux2"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: As suggested by Arpit Agarwal, navigating to

```
http://localhost:3000/shell/(department/1(aux2:test3))
```

does the trick:

[image: Test3 is rendered inside Shell]

However, take a look at the URL after page load. If I press `F5` now, I'm back to square one:

> platform-browser.umd.js:1900 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'shell'

EDIT 2: Here's the [link to the project on github](https://github.com/erasethis/angular2-aux-test).

Comment: Can you try http://localhost:3000/shell/(department/1(aux2:test3)) this will not show test2comp as URL doesn't have path for it.

Comment: That actually renders Test3 inside aux2, but there's a catch: The URL is changed to http://localhost:3000/shell/(/(department/1//aux2:test3)) after page load and then the whole thing breaks down again with "Cannot match any routes: 'shell'" on page refresh.

Comment: Try http://localhost:3000/shell/(department/1//aux2:test3) or http://localhost:3000/shell/(department;id=1//aux2:test3). You may need to remove Id from route definition for later to work

Comment: localhost:3000/shell/(department/1//aux2:test3) works, the other one is broken. You should make that an actual answer, I'd be very interested in why the URL has to take that form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using http://localhost:3000/shell/(department/1//aux2:test3)

URL has format `(primaryroute//secondaryroute)`
parentheses tells it may have sibling routes and `//` is sibling route separator.

Aux and primary outlets are considered sibling on same parent

Comment: `routerLink="/shell(department/1//aux2:test3)"` doesn't seem to work, but `router.navigateByUrl( "/shell(department/1//aux2:test3)" );` works just fine.

Comment: Yes. There seems to be some issue in routerLink to navigate to aux routes. Not sure if a bug is logged or not.  Will check and update

Answer (score 1):

some working example
[click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LIosdPx1MCe2NQDDiQn8?p=preview)

important points

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-one',{ outlets: { 'sidebar': ['component-aux'] } }]">Component One</a>

@Component({
  selector: 'component-one',
  template: `Component One
    <div style="color: green; margin-top: 1rem;">Sidebar Outlet:</div>
    <div style="border: 2px solid blue; padding: 1rem;">
      <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
```