# What does a valid [routerLink] look like for a relative aux route?

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

Let's say I got this route config:

```
{ path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent, children: [
    { path: ':id', component: ContactDetailComponent },
    { path: 'chat', component: ContactChatComponent, outlet: 'chat' }
]}
```

If I navigate to

```
/contact/7
```

I arrive at contact detail, but how do I get to the aux route from there? That is, what do I need to put in my `[routerLink]`?

I know I can easily get there with an absolute URL such as

```
/contact/(7//chat:chat)
```

but what if I need to use a relative link here? What form does that have to take? I've tried

```
[routerLink]="['chat:chat']"
[routerLink]="['//chat:chat']"
[routerLink]="['(7//chat:chat)']"
```

and so on, but none of those creates the link that actually works (see above).

I'm on RC4 with router 3.0.0-beta2.

Comment: I know it would be extra work for you but a [plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-1/ts/plnkr.html) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) might be good to reproduce this so that we can fiddle with it as well

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Seems plnkr can't deal with these kinds of URL, `GET http://run.plnkr.co/contact/(7//aux:chat) 400 (Bad Request)` - for what it's worth, the plnkr is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OwS5RR6dBeKzh31HeE3G

Comment: yea... plnkr does need some work on angular 2 apps... But on your question, you say that navigating to `/contact/(7//aux:chat)` loads everything properly?

Comment: Yes it should, my actual setup is somewhat different though (I use these auxiliary routes to navigate to modal dialogs and sure enough, they pop up). See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38223710/370935

Comment: After banging the keyboard a little, I decided to look into the open issues on github and found this - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9957

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there appears to be a bug or two in `[routerLink]`, so I had to come up with a workaround. As I already hinted at in a comment to my original question I use these auxiliary routes in order to navigate to a modal dialog, e.g.

```
/contacts
```

will display a list of contacts and

```
/(contacts//aux:new)
```

is supposed to open a modal dialog *on top* of the list of contacts instead of rendering inside that same container and hiding the list.

I achieved the same effect by introducing a dummy component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'aux-route-workaround',
    template: ''
})
export class AuxRouteWorkaroundComponent { }
```

The routing configuration then takes the form

```
export const ContactsComponentRoutes = [
    { 
        path: 'contacts', 
        component: ContactsComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: AuxRouteWorkaroundComponent },
            { path: 'new', component: NewContactComponent }
        ]
    } 
];
```

and the template for `ContactsComponent` becomes

```
template: `
    <contacts-list></contacts-list>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
```

So if now I navigate to

```
/contacts
```

the `''` is activated, that is `ContactListComponent` is rendered, as is the workaround component (the template of which is empty, so it adds nothing to the view).

Using

```
[routerLink]="['new']"
```

I can then navigate (relatively) to

```
/contacts/new
```

and this time the dialog component is rendered for the `<router-outlet>`, showing both components, `ContactsListComponent` and `NewContactComponent` inside the same parent component - as they would using auxiliary routes.

Mission accomplished.