# Angular2 navigate from a component to a sibling component without tearing down the first

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I've just started learning Angular2 and I want to build a very common "list-detail" style page similar to this: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/index.html . When you click an item in left-bar it initiates a navigation to the center detail view without tearing down the left-bar. What's the best way to achieve this effect?

My current design is like the following:
[image]

When I start the home component, the list component(child1) will load immediately and it will call an external API to fetch the names (only names) of a list of items. When clicking a item name on the left, it will create a new Detail-component. The detail component fetch item detail in its ngOnInit method. I've tried using auxiliary routes to nest the two child components on the same page but it does not seem to work. My home routes look like this:

```
export const HomeRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':item',
        component: DetailComponent
        outlet: 'detail'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And in my `home.component.ts` I simply have this:

```
  <h2>Home</h2>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <router-outlet name="detail"></router-outlet>
```

And the way I navigate to the detail view is calling navigate() in the list-component like this:

```
onSelect(item : string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', item]);
  }
```

But everytime I click the any of the items the detail view does not show up and it shows error like this:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'home/item'
.
```

Am I on the right track of using Auxiliary route and is there any better way to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current router version has some issues in navigating to aux outlet using `routerLink` and `navigate` method. You should build the full URL and use `navigateByUrl`.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/(list//detail:detail)
```

Plunker with [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kn4yBi5oytNVcFvUvGLR?p=preview). Click on detail button and then admin. Admin is routed in admin outlet.  Open in full screen to see URL formation.

The URL has following semantics

1. Child path is separated by /
2. If a path has siblings then it should be surrounded with parenthesis
3. Sibling are separated by //
4. Outlet and path is separated by :

   Parent/child/(gchild1//outletname:gchild2)

Another so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38224857/652850)

Comment: Is there any reason behind the parenthesis in "/home/(list//detail:detail" ? instead of just "home/list/:item"?

Comment: Indeed  updated the answe with reason. I will link another q where u explained this but that may take some time

Comment: The problem is I don't have a sibling path. I only have two sibling components with one (list component) having the same path as the home component. The other sibling component(detail) has a path that takes a parameter :item. How do I write the url in this case?

Comment: Ok, another neat solution is to make the left bar a directive of home. Then it just needs to have a single <router-outlet> for the detail component.