# angular 2 new router rc4 child's aux route doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Aux route inside child route, don't know how to set to let it work.
i have root component and route config file  like:

```
root.routes.ts     
 export const rootRoute:RouterConfig=[
       ...ChildrenRoute,
       {path:'',component:ChildrenRootComponent},
       {path:'children-root',component:ChildrenRootComponent},
       {path:'other',component:OtherComponent'}
  ];

 template:
          '<a routerLink='children-root'>Children root</a>
           <a routerLink='other'>Other</a>
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>'
```

and ChildrenRootComponent have FirstComponent and SecondComponent with routes config file like:

```
 children.routes.ts    
     export const ChildrenRoute:RouterConfig=[
        {path:"",redirectTo:'/children-root',pathMatch:'full'},
        {path:'children-root',component:ChildrenRootComponent,
               children:[
                    {path:'',component:FirstComponent},
                    {path:'first',component:FirstComponent},
                    {path:'second',component:SecondComponent,outlet:'aux'}
               ]
        }
    ];
template:
         ' <a routerLink='first'>First</a>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
           <a routerLink='aux:second'>Second</a>
              <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>'
```

Now route from **Children root -> Second** is ok, but route **Children root -> first** doesn't work show error:

```
 Error: Cannot match any routes: 'children-root/second'
```

change template:

```
   ' <a routerLink='first'>First</a>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     <a routerLink='(aux:second)'>Second</a>
          <router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>'
```

doesn't work too. error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'children-root/second)'
```

pay attention here ')' in error message,and no '(' . 
directly set url as following in browser

```
 localhost:4200/children-root/(aux:second)
```

reload and work well. so i guess i set routerLink wrong, search a lot, no find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has just been fixed. We shall see it working in the upcoming **RC.5**

[related GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10351#issuecomment-238407182)

Answer (score 1):

RC.4 doesn't support routerLink with aux routes yet. Try something like this:

`<a href="/children-root/(aux:second)">Second</a>`

Comment: a href can go to SecondComponent, but browser reload full page, not just load SecondComponent in router-outlet.

Comment: this href shouldn't reload the page. At lease in my app I use HashLocationStrategy and the URL similar to this one doesn't reload the page:
```<a href="#/children-root/(aux:second)">Second</a>```

Comment: This is still an issue in RC.5 .. I wonder when this might get solved

Answer (score 1):

Rc4. Doesn't support routerLink properly yet. You can achieve the desired result using `navigateByUrl` or  manual  'a' tag. 
I assume your first componet is visible when you try to navigate to second.  Then try

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/children-root/(first//aux:second)');
```

Or

```
<a href="/children-root/(first//aux:second)">Second</a>
```

The explanation of route URL formation can be read at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572458/652850)

Comment: how about rc1 and 3.0.0.alpha.x support routerLink better? someone used?

Comment: 3.0.0.beta2 is latest for router and no earlier version has better support. rest of angular package version is immaterial